# String input distributed to array (Android)?

Tags: android, arrays, algorithm, stemming, porter-stemmer

I've been looking for answer regarding my question but I cannot find one or maybe I'm not just using the right terms when searching.

My question is, how can I distribute string entered in an editText to an array?

This is about my porter2 stemming project. I need to distribute the strings entered in the `EditText` field to an array so i can scan whether `x` in `array[x]` is vowel or not.

Ex.
String in `EditText` field = `"dog"`.

Array should be:

```
array[0] = d
array[1] = o
array[2] = g
```

I'm sorry that i cannot give a code because I really don't have any idea how to code this one. Thank you so much everyone. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use use [`.split()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) with an empty (`""`) string input:

```
String text = yourEditText.getText().toString();
String[] letters = text.split(""); // Split by empty string to be in an array
// letters == { "", "d", "o", "g" }
//              ^ Note that this has an empty string element at the front; that's just a byproduct of how split() works.
```

If you want a `char` array instead, it's much easier to use [`.toCharArray()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray%28%29):

```
String text = yourEditText.getText().toString();
char[] letters = text.toCharArray();
// letters == { 'd', 'o', 'g' };
```

Personally I'd use the second one; `letter == 'a'` is a much faster operation than `letter.equals("a")`.

Comment: Hello Eric! Thank you for the response. Worked like charm. I can now proceed with the stemming procedure. Cheers! Happy New Year :)

Comment: by the way, may I know how I can use the max number of array in a for loop?

//


for( int x = letters.length ; x >= 0 ; x--)     {
 if (letters[x] == 's' || letters[x] == 'S')
 {
  letters[x] = 'Z';
  sb.append(letters);
  mtv.setText(sb.toString());
}

//


My app force closes when I use letters.length. I need the initial value of 'x' to be the same as the number of letters the word have.

Comment: Start with `letters.length - 1`. (In a 6-element array, the last element's number is 5.)